# Parsing a dataset with different dateformats

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-cleaning

I have a dataset in a pandas DataFrame. I have a column that holds the time when you can move in into an apartment. This data is super messy, containing freely written strings like: `"now", "custom agreement"` but also dates, written as strings, in the format of `"01.06.2018", "September 2017", "01. Februrary 2017", "2017-09-01"`.

I manage to ignore all cases that are not translateable into a dateformat such as `"now"`, but my parsing fails to correctly parse the different date formats. As you can see, the format is not always dayfirst. If no day is specified it is fine to take the first of the month.

Does anyone has an idea on how to tackle this task?

Comment: How big is your data? maybe after you clear out all the strings you can open it in excel and let it handle all different formats, then change the format to something unique and go from there

Comment: `pandas.to_datetime()` will parse everything one of those date formates you specified without issue. Of course it assumes `01.06.2018` is January 6th and not June 1st. You'll perhaps need to use regex to separate different formats if that's not the case and apply pd.to_datetime separately